# Bash getopts dropping last argument

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, getopts

So, I'm trying my hand at using bash's built-in getopts to handle argument processing except I'm getting a strange result. Here's my test script;

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST=
OWNER=
GROUP=

while getopts "h:o:g" OPTION;
  do
    case $OPTION in
    h)
      HOST=$OPTARG
      ;;
    o)
      OWNER=$OPTARG
      ;;
    g)
      GROUP=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done

echo "$HOST - $OWNER:$GROUP"
```

Yet, when I run the script using this;

```
./test.sh -h test.host.com -o skittles -g whatever
```

My last arg never gets pulled in or is getting dropped. My result from the echo is;

```
test.host.com - skittles:
                         ^ where's my group value? O.o
```

Does anyone know what would be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems your expect `-g` to have an argument, but in your options declaration, there is no ":" related to your `-g`.

You should have this:

```
h:o:g:
```

Comment: Thank you Ouki! I was not aware that a colon had to succeed each option. The reason that I missed that was because of this example I used to try it. http://rsalveti.wordpress.com/2007/04/03/bash-parsing-arguments-with-getopts/

Comment: It is quite explictly said in the [bash getopt man page](http://ss64.com/bash/getopts.html) : "If a character is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument."

Answer (score 3):

Your option string is missing a `:` after the g.

Comment: Thank you William! I apologize that I couldn't accept both answers as they obviously were both correct. I do appreciate the response nonetheless.